# How can I refactor/abstract ngrx actions to be less prone to typos?

Tags: typescript, redux, refactoring, action, ngrx

**Update:**
It seems like typescript-fsa maybe the opinionated library I'm looking for https://github.com/aikoven/typescript-fsa/issues/40. Any help on implementation details would be awesome!

I feel like when I'm doing [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/), I'm constantly copying & pasting files & then just renaming parts.  It's pretty prone to my typical fat finger errors. While I'm not currently testing my project, if a project was to required 100% code coverage, this could be an even more tedious task.

Example of a trivial action, called Counter:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export const INCREMENT  = '[Counter] Increment';
export const DECREMENT  = '[Counter] Decrement';
export const RESET      = '[Counter] Reset';

export class Increment implements Action {
  readonly type = INCREMENT;
}

export class Decrement implements Action {
  readonly type = DECREMENT;
}

export class Reset implements Action {
  readonly type = RESET;

  constructor(public payload: number) {}
}

export type All
  = Increment
  | Decrement
  | Reset;
```

### **Question:**

**In typescript is there any pattern to get the functionality of these set of classes shown above with a simple function call?**

**An example would be:**

`TypeAction.create('Animal', ['Add', 'Remove', 'Reset'])`

*Note: this is a contrived function signature, as it doesn't take into account the payload its types but is just for example?*

but this function could generate/represent/work like the code below:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export const ADD = '[Animal] Add';
export const REMOVE = '[Animal] Remove';
export const RESET      = '[Animal] Reset';

export class Add implements Action {
  readonly type = ADD;
}

export class Remove implements Action {
  readonly type = REMOVE;
}

export class Reset implements Action {
  readonly type = RESET;

  constructor() {}
}

export type All
  = Add
  | Remove
  | Reset
```

Lastly, please no reflection as this isn't a good solution.  Also, "this isn't possible" could be an acceptable answer too...

Comment: It isn't just you, correct implementation of ngrx/store is very repetitive, I did do some work on a package to reduce this, but it added extra complexity. The best bet is to have multiple action/reducer files and combine with a tidy index file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution is to use an action generator like [typescript-fsa](https://github.com/aikoven/typescript-fsa)*

So, instead of "native" NgRx action classes, you could define action *generators*, e.g.

```
import { actionCreatorFactory } from 'typescript-fsa';

const counter = actionCreatorFactory('counter');
export const counterIncrement = counter('INCREMENT');
export const counterDecrement = counter('DECREMENT');
export const counterReset = counter<number>('RESET');
```

The generated actions will then be named 'counter/INCREMENT' etc.

Use them in your reducers like so:

```
import { isType } from 'typescript-fsa';

export function counterReducer(state: CounterState = initialState, action: Action) {
  if (isType(action, counterIncrement)) {
    return { ...state, < your reduction here > };
  }
  if (isType(action, counterDecrement)) {
    return { ...state, < your reduction here > };
  }
  if (isType(action, counterReset)) {
    return { ...state, < your reduction here > };
  }
  return state;
};
```

And dispatch these as

```
store.dispatch(counterIncrement());
store.dispatch(counterDecrement());
store.dispatch(counterReset(42));
```

Finally, in your effects

```
@Effect() counterIncrement$ = this.actions$
  .filter(counterIncrement.match)
  .map(action => ...)

@Effect() counterDecrement$ = this.actions$
  .filter(counterDecrement.match)
  .map(action => ...)

@Effect() counterReset$ = this.actions$
  .filter(counterReset.match)
  .map(action => action.payload)
  .map(payload => ...)
```

As you can see, you never use typo-prone action strings besides the initial definition, instead you import typed action generators, which provides additional safety and also enables function replacement in typescript-aware code editors.

If your actions are *homogeneous* across collections, i.e. each collection has *identical* "ADD", "REMOVE", "RESET", etc. actions (but a different "collection" prefix; and not every collection has to implement all of these), then you can go a step further and create *generic* action generators, a *generic* reducer generator, etc. so you will not have to duplicate otherwise identical code multiple times.

EDIT: Per Matthew's request, [here](https://github.com/cumulous/web/tree/master/src/app/store)'s a more advanced example that incorporates generics and NgRX entities**.

*not an author of that package

**I am an author of that example. It is a bit unwieldy (and beyond the focus of this question) to paste the full example here, but do let me know if sharing that link is not appropriate.

Comment: I haven't used them but the new entity package.  Does it play nicely with fsa? If so, could you be so kind to add it to the question

Comment: Yes, it does - not sure where to add it though - could you be more specific? Btw, I did publish the full code so let me know if you need a full example (not sure it's appropriate to link here).

Comment: The entity package is just suppose to reduce boilerplate. I haven't read much into it other than that. If my simple example can't really take advantage of entities than let's just leave it out. Also, If you have your live code just update the question. . Like "here is a more robust repo to learn from. I think ppl will appreciate this going forward.

Answer (score 0):

little bit upgrade proposed scaffolding

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Animal } from 'animal.models';

export const ADD = '[Auth] Add';

export class Add implements Action {
  readonly type = ADD;
  constructor(public payload: Animal[]) {}
}
```

im thinking to achieve something better and rly NGRX/redux/flux way with crud async actions is scared first time, i using what apollo team do with them internal async store with sync options and i think its a future, it was nice manage options with one source of true, they create generic actions mechanism for CRUD* actions, when u want do something special, you can use DI and write your reducer for store with immutable function, or i can think u can use effects (i never try yet)

why i think is a future ?
apollo 2.0 don't need from u repeat the code for CRUD actions, every time write effects for catch the async server actions in plus schema is securing your types with introspection to ts (generators are ready to production), im very optimistic for https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/whats-coming-in-apollo-client-2-0-bcd8ea64acbd (wroted by James Baxley III) and "Future features" paragraph -
 when this future will be the now writting mutations one store and sync state between servers, browsers, p2p live, will be amazing...

Comment: ahh yeah sure that makes the typing better.  But still doesn't help how verbose it is :(